# SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\x90' in file .\score_python.exe on line 1, but no encoding declared;

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller

I have a python script where I need to create an executable via `pyinstaller`. Successfully created the `exe`, but shows the above error while running.

I have already searched on the web and tried many solutions but none of them is working. tried with `# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-` in the first line of the script but fails.

using `Python3.7`, `PyInstaller3.5`

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\x90' in file C:\Python36\python.exe on line 1, but no encoding declared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47393026/syntaxerror-non-utf-8-code-starting-with-x90-in-file-c-python36-python-exe)

Comment: @Wolfeius but how do I know which char is that?

Comment: @00 but that doesn't resolve my issue.

Comment: @ArunAugustine You could write a script that does it :D.  Check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33274428/python-change-character-encoding-to-utf-8 if this solves your problem

Comment: Does the score_python.exe file identify as a proper executable to Windows?

Comment: yes, it's a proper executable to Windows with syntax error.

Comment: reinstalling python solved my issue.

Answer (score 18):

**Ensure you are not calling the executable using python again.**

As in

```
python long-path-to-the-converted-scrip\script.exe
```

It is a common mistake, due to the fact that you used python to run the script before, then you try to recycle the same command **but forget to delete the python call**. The long path to the script (now converted to exe) obfuscates the fact that **python is no longer needed at the beginning**...hence your error.

Comment: but I have to use python to call it again

Answer (score 0):

Resolution: Please execute the exe without python command.

Example: If you have converted test.py, please go to the directory Current Directory/dist/test/ and either double-click on test.exe or run test.exe from command line.

Comment: In what way does this differ from the other answer from 9 months ago?