# awsebcli 'SyntaxError- no encoding declared' in terminal upon executing any eb command

Tags: python, django, utf-8

I finished django project and during deployment run into error- after installing awsebcli package I try to run eb commands in terminal but get this error:

```
File "C:\Users\Bartski\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts\eb.exe", line 1
SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\x90' in file C:\Users\Bartski\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts\eb.exe on line 1, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
```

It shows the same error no matter what eb command I try to run. awsebcli installs only exe version so I am not able to change the encoding manually.

I tried many solutions given to similar problems but none of them worked so far.

Any ideas how can I make it work?

Comment: What command are you running? `python <path>/eb.exe`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\x90' in file .\score\_python.exe on line 1, but no encoding declared;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57391014/syntaxerror-non-utf-8-code-starting-with-x90-in-file-score-python-exe-on-l)

Comment: I tried any of them: `eb create` nor `eb init -p python-3.7 <project_name>` don't work. I don't call python first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I finally solved it! Posting answer just in case someone will ever struggle with something similar.

So the problem was a PATH. Strangely- I did have a correct path in PATH variable in system variables window (in menu start in case you are wondering) however for some reason it was not being called correctly- I am guessing maybe because I had a lot of other paths in there, maybe if there are too many it causes some conflicts.

So what I did I cleared PATH var (from user variables) as well as Path var and PYTHONPATH var (from system variables) and I only entered 1 single path (leading to my Scripts folder within Python installation) into user PATH var. This way awsebcli finally worked! I will be adding systematically the rest of paths I had in PATH var (heroku, git etc.) and keeping a close look at any other potential conflicts.

If you know what is the reason that paths get mixed up like that please don't hesitate to say in comment.